# Move-ADObject Cannot find an object with identity

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to move the below machines to other OUs
I have a csv like this:

[image]

And I am trying to move them with the code below:

```
$computers =  Import-Csv 'C:\Reports\Win7.csv' 

foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
Move-ADObject -Identity $computer.Name  -TargetPath "OU=Disabled, OU=Computers, OU=Resources ,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=loc" 
}
```

But I don't know why I get the following error :

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'WSJ0HZ45J' under:
```

Which is strange because I can find this machine in AD ..

Any suggestions?

Update

I think i know why it did not worked

I did as below and it helped!

```
$computers =  Import-Csv 'C:\Reports\Win7.csv' 
$BaseOU = "OU=Disabled,OU=Computers,OU=Resources,OU=DataManagement,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=loc"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
Get-adcomputer $computer.Name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $BaseOU
}
```

Thanks  for help anyway!

Comment: Try removing the `,` characters and blank lines from your .csv file.

Comment: Running `Move-ADObject -Identity WSJ0HZ45J  -TargetPath "OU=Disabled, OU=Computers, OU=Resources ,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=loc"` is successful?

Comment: Put a , after WSJ0HZ45J in the last line of the file to make it consistent, since that's the one throwing the error.  I mean, the comma should just be treated as a delimiter but it's missing the comma in that last line.

Comment: adding ',' at last li ne did not helped. Command move-adobject for single name do not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding the *-Identity* parameter a canonical computer name.  Per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-adobject?view=win10-ps), the only acceptable values for *-Identity* parameter are:

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)

Please change your code snippet to the DN value of the computer name and it should work.  Below is an example for the one machine based on my guess of where it is in Active Directory.  Change computer name to a variable accordingly inside of your script.

```
Move-ADObject -Identity "DN=WSJ0HZ45JOU,OU=Computers,OU=Resources,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=loc"  -TargetPath "OU=Disabled,OU=Computers,OU=Resources,DC=hello,DC=world,DC=loc"
```